# Can the following nonlinear first order ODE be solved?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I have tried solving this equation from several manners but no luck. Can it be solved?
$$\frac{d f}{d t} = A f^2 +g(t)$$

The solution for the homogeneous is (I think; somebody should confirm)
$$f_h(t) = -\frac{1}{At + C},$$
where $C$ is a constant. So substituting back would be 
$$\frac{\frac{dC(t)}{dt}+A}{(C(t)+A t )^2} = A \left(\frac{-1}{At + C}\right)^2 + g(t)$$

but that's where I stopped...
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the homogeneous?

Comment: Yes, the but resulting equation by variation of parameters seems worse. I couldn't solve that either. I'll edit and put the equation there.

Comment: For me, this one looks like Ricatti equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{d f}{d t} = A f^2 +g(t)$$
Let $f(t)=-\frac{1}{A\:h(t)}\frac{d h}{dt}$ which leads to :
$$\frac{d^2h}{dt^2}+A\,g(t)h(t)=0$$
It is well-known that this kind of second order linear ODE can be analytically solved for some forms of functions $g(t)$ and cannot for many others.

So, it is impossible to answer to the question if the function $g(t)$ is not explicitly defined.

Comment: Thank you, but by "solvable", I meant be put in dependence of a sole integral that depends on $g(t)$. Your answer completely solves the question, though.